# I'll drop my current development line and use one from another repo instead - how to correctly handle this?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am currently developing a multi-stage project for a course I'm assisting to . I'm over with the first phase of the project. As for the second part I'll want to start with the code my professor has already done for the first stage, for he is doing it in parallel with us(actually, a bit ahead of us) to make sure what he's asking us to do is actually feasible!. My professor's code is in another repo.

Now, my question is on how to handle this. My gut is telling I should create a tag `phase1` and put my current trunk contents there. Afterwards I'll just have to erase all the contents in the trunk and checkout my professor's code to some folder on my hard drive (it seems I cannot just checkout it to my trunk folder directly!). After that, I'll copy what I just checked out in my trunk and hit commit.

Is this a correct approximation? I realize this one will work, I'm just wondering whether this is the cleanest and appropriate way to accomplish the task!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svn mv` your `trunk` to sometwhere else, like `branches/phase1`, then `svn mkdir` a new `trunk` where you can check in your professor's code, or `svn import` your professor's code into a new `trunk`.

**Edit:** As @forsvarir points out, it's probably a good idea to put the professor's code on its own branch so you can merge from it as needed.

So after moving your original `trunk`, `svn import` the professors code to `branches/professor` (or whatever name), and `svn copy` `branches/professor` to `trunk`, this way you can add the professors changes to `branches/professor` as he updates his code, and you can merge those changes to `trunk`.

Comment: +1: You beat me to it! This way there's no history between the student's work and the tutor's work which is probably what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If I was doing this...

I'd set up the Trunk as the Professor's development line.  Each time the Professor gives you a new drop of code, update this version accordingly and then branch it for your own development (as phase XXXX).  That way, there's an obvious flow through the code for how you got to each point.  I would expect if you did this, you should be able to check out your trunk, then merge the changes directly from the Professor's repository (starting from the revision you last took, and up to the revision that the Professor has presumably tagged as the start of the next phase).

With your current setup, I'd follow the approach suggested by @Christoffer.

Comment: +1: Good point, it's probably a good idea to make the professor's code its own branch and merge from it to trunk as the professor updates it.